# Stop PyCharm from "Scanning installed packages..." on every program start for already scanned projects

Tags: python, pycharm

### Default PyCharm behavior

**Every time** when

- I start PyCharm IDE application
- or re-open (restart) the PyCharm IDE application
- or re-open my existing project,

...PyCharm starts "Updating python interpreter" and "Scanning installed packages...".

### Problems

1. The project is located on my hard drive and was already 100% scanned. Nothing new to scan again.
2. The project or project requirements did not change. Nothing to scan again.
3. I would be happy to allow this background scans, but:

   - they are very slow (~5-10 minutes);
   - they are just totally useless because nothing changes between restarts.

### What I want

Stop PyCharm from this useless resource-wasting slow unnecessary scans of already scanned projects.

Comment: Same problem here.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible way to stop this behavior.
You can just close the project in the 'Files' menu, and re-open the project. ( Don't just close the window and re-open the project, it doesn't work)

I've tried this way and pycharm stops updating the interpreter. Good luck.